# how to get NSMutableArray From NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutableArray as below.

```
(
        {
        ClientId = "17";
        FileURL = "http://www.xxx.com/b0a89db3-482b-464e-81ae-78439527c702.jpg";
    },
        {
        ClientId = "56";
        FileURL = "http://www.xxx.com/f7633371-b726-4332-9b26-a98a2fed991d.jpg";
    }
)
```

What I want is NSMutableArray which will look similar to below.

```
NSMutableArray *image_array = 
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
    @"http://www.xxx.com/b0a89db3-482b-464e-81ae-78439527c702.jpg", 
    @"http://www.xxx.com/f7633371-b726-4332-9b26-a98a2fed991d.jpg", 
    nil];
```

Any idea how to do that?

---

I tried with

```
NSArray *filtered = [feeds filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(FileURL CONTAINS[cd] %@)", @"%http%"]];
NSLog(@"filter====%@", filtered);
```

but I am not getting anything. Data is blank.

---

Actually I have main array in below format.

```
(
        {
        ClientId = "17\n    ";
        FileURL = "http://www.xxx.com/b0a89db3-482b-464e-81ae-78439527c702.jpg\n\n";
    },
        {
        ClientId = "56\n    ";
        FileURL = "http://www.xxx.com/f7633371-b726-4332-9b26-a98a2fed991d.jpg\n\n";
    }
)
```

Any idea how to remove those `\n` and white spaces while creating new array?

Comment: Is it an array of dictionaries? Why not just iterate over them and grab the data?

Comment: There are methods in `NSString` like `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` that'll let you remove the newlines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use KVC to get the array:

```
[[array valueForKey:@"FileURL"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I believe this gives back an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @rmaddy, I can't test right now but I think you're right so I've edited.